# Some strange errors when using less

Tags: less

There are many strange errors when I using less in VSCode. Here is an example:

```
#library() {
    .colors() {
      primary: green;
      secondary: blue;
    }
  }

#library() {
    .colors() { primary: grey; }
}

.button {
    color: #library.colors[primary];
    border-color: #library.colors[secondary];
}
```

compiled file:

```css
.button {
  color: #library.colors[primary];
  border-color: #library.colors[secondary];
}
```

```
line13: error: property value expectedless(css-propertyvalueexpected)
line14: error: { expectedless(css-lcurlyexpected)
line15: error: at-rule or selector expectedless(css-ruleorselectorexpected)
```

This is an example that I copied from http://lesscss.org on how to use map. I also noticed that map is a new feature which has been enabled since v3.5. But my LESS version is v3.10.